# Skip one file but remain part of the repository

Tags: git

My project has one file that contains the database connection and private API key. For others using my project, that file is needed, but of course they shouldn't get access to my private API key.

What would be the best way to manage this? Just upload the anonymised file once to github and don't include it in my repository? Or is there a better way to have a local file with the private stuf and an anonymised online version.

Gabrie

Comment: Your private key should be stored in a separate file that is *referenced* by your project, not in the project itself.

Comment: More generally, the key (or file containing the key) needed to connect to the database should be a configuration option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about it is to add and commit an anonymised version of your file, then issue the following command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

(See docs for [git-update-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index).)

Git will then ignore any changes to this file, so you can add your private stuff to it and not have it added to index and committed by accident.

The downside, of course, is that this will only affect your local repository. Other developers, working on your project, would still have this file monitored for changes, unless they execute the same command in their own local repo.

It's also a bit fiddly, since, if you want to change something in this file and have these changes committed, you'll have to execute the reverse command:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

And then make sure to commit only non-private changes (either temporarily removing your private stuff, or using interactive add), after which you'll want to run the original command again, to make Git oblivious to further changes once more.